# weka , java , MultilabelArffFileStream.java

Tags: java, stream, weka

I have two question in class of MultilabelArffFileStream.java

1- What is the meaning of Integer.MAX_VALUE in line 42-43
https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~abifet/MOA/API/_multilabel_arff_file_stream_8java_source.html/

2- The class would read the ARFFfile till when , what is the limitation

Answer (score 0):

Cannot access the file that you linked to. However, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum (biggest) value that can be represented by a Java Integer, which is 2^31-1 or 2147483647.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE